# JavaScript array application

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a sample accounting system, the checkbox can be add to the total after it's checked and the input text is the amount of the money.
but my result keep getting zero, I can't figure it out. 
Anyone can help me handle this problem?
**I've test that the length of total_ary is 0, I think that is the mainly problem**

```js
function Totalamount() {
  var input_cb = document.getElementsByName('cb');
  var amount = [];
  var total_ary = [];
  var total = 0;
  var price = [10, 20, 30];
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < input_cb.length; i++) {
    if (input_cb[i].checked) {
      amount.push(document.getElementsByName("amount").value); //get amounts of the products
    } else {
      amount.push(0); //If there is no input, add 0 to the array
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < total_ary.length; i++) {
    total_ary.push(parseInt(amount[i] * price[i])); // Add the products' total price to array
    total += parseInt(total_ary[i]); //Counting the total money
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "$" + 0;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "$" + total ;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$10：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$20：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$30：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="Totalamount()">Count</button>
<p>Total = <span id="result">
```

Comment: Review your HTML. There are tons of syntax errors.  Fix them first !

Comment: Hint: There's a major bug on this line: `amount.push( parseInt( document.getElementsByName( "amount" ).value ) )`. `getElementsByName` returns a collection of HTML elements, not a single element, so `.value` will throw an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
Errors that I identified.

1. Making use of `document.getElementsByName("amount").value` instead of making the respective amount field you were making use of the global selector.
2. Trying to loop `total_ar`y array instead of `amount` array.

```js
function Totalamount() {
    var input_cb = document.getElementsByName('cb');
    var amountInput = document.getElementsByName('amount');
    var amount = [];
    var total_ary = [];
    var total = 0;
    var price = [10,20,30];
    var i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < input_cb.length; i++) {
        if (input_cb[i].checked && amountInput[i].value){
            amount.push(parseInt(amountInput[i].value)); //get amounts of the products
        }
        else{
            amount.push(0); //If there is no input, add 0 to the array
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
        total_ary.push(parseInt(amount[i] * price[i])); // Add the products' total price to array
        total += parseInt(total_ary[i]); //Counting the total money
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "$" + 0;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total + "元";
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type = "checkbox" name="cb" checked>$10
  <input type="text" id="amount_milk" name="amount" ><br>

  <input type = "checkbox" name="cb" checked>$20
  <input type="text" id="amount_soymlik" name="amount"><br>

  <input type = "checkbox" name="cb" checked>$30
  <input type="text" id="amount_blacktea" name="amount" ><br>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="Totalamount()">Count</button>
<p>Total = <span id="result">
```

Comment: Yours is returning NaN's

Comment: @D.Foley please check was some error with the editor I think. Was working correct in my local. have corrected that now.

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
document.getElementsByName("amount").value
```

but `getElementsByName` returns a collection, not an element.

You do

```
var total_ary = [];
// ... code that doesn't reference total_ary
for (i = 0; i < total_ary.length; i++) {
  total_ary.push(parseInt(amount[i] * price[i])); // Add the products' total price to array
  total += parseInt(total_ary[i]); //Counting the total money
}
```

But since the code in between doesn't reference `total_ary`, the `total` ends up being 0.

From a selected checkbox, you need to navigate to the associated input:

```
document.getElementsByName("amount")[i].value
```

since `i` is the `cb` index you're iterating over, the same `i` in the `amount` collection will refer to the input you need.

Or, more elegantly, just navigate to the next element in the DOM when a checkbox is checked, and take the number for each product's price from the DOM too. You can also select only the checked checkboxes immediately with a `:checked` selector, and attach the event listener using `addEventListener` (instead of an inline handler; inline handlers [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045))

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let total = 0;
  for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('[name=cb]:checked')) {
    const price = input.nextSibling.textContent.match(/\d+/)[0];
    const amount = input.nextElementSibling.value;
    total += price * amount;
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total + "元";
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$10：<input><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$20：<input><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$30：<input><br>
</fieldset>
<button>Count</button>
<p>Total = <span id="result">
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName()` returns a collection of elements. so calling `value` property will not work there as it does not have such property.

You can hold input elements with `amount_inputs` variable and iterate over it (in the example below by using `spread syntax` and `Array.reduce()`)

And with `Array.reduce()` you can calculate the sum of the prices. There is no need for `var amount = []` and `var total_ary = []` variables.

Hope this helps

```js
function Totalamount() {
  var input_cb = document.getElementsByName('cb');
  var amount_inputs = document.getElementsByName("amount")
  var total = 0;
  var price = [10, 20, 30];
  
  
  total = [...input_cb].reduce((total, cb, i) => {
    if(cb.checked){
      total += (parseInt(amount_inputs[i].value) || 0) * price[i]
      //                                     ^^^^^^^^^ This is to avoid NaN multiplication
    }
    return total
  },0);
  
  
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "$" + 0;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total + "元";
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$10：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$20：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$30：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="Totalamount()">Count</button>
<p>Total = <span id="result">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Index while retrieving the element from document.getElementsByName("amount");
2. Use for loop on amount array not on total_ary

```js
function Totalamount() {
  var input_cb = document.getElementsByName('cb');
  var amount = [];
  var total_ary = [];
  var total = 0;
  var price = [10, 20, 30];
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < input_cb.length; i++) {
    if (input_cb[i].checked) {
      amount.push(document.getElementsByName("amount")[i].value); //get amounts of the products
    } else {
      amount.push(0); //If there is no input, add 0 to the array
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
    total_ary.push(parseInt(amount[i] * price[i])); // Add the products' total price to array
    total += isNaN(parseInt(total_ary[i])) ? 0 : parseInt(total_ary[i]); //Counting the total money
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "$" + 0;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "$" + total ;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$10：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$20：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked>$30：<input type="text"  name="amount"><br>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="Totalamount()">Count</button>
<p>Total = <span id="result">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a few mistakes:

(1) If you want to keep all the checkboxes checked at initial stage
    use **checked="true"** in place of **checked**

(2) **getElementsByName("amount")** returns an array, so you should use the index as well

(3) total_ary length is 0 initially.. therefore, you should run the loop with input_cb. (Here, you can do both the task with a single loop: refer code below)

Refer the code with corrections:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>Order sys
<script>
function Totalamount() {
    var input_cb = document.getElementsByName('cb');
    var amount = [];
    var total = 0;
    var price = [10,20,30];
    var i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < input_cb.length; i++) {
        if (input_cb[i].checked){
            amount.push(parseInt(document.getElementsByName("amount")[i].value)); //get amounts of the products
        }
        else{
            amount.push(0); //If there is no input, add 0 to the array
        }

        total += parseInt(amount[i] * price[i]) //Counting the total money
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "$" + 0;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total + "元";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<input type = "checkbox" name="cb" checked="true">$10：<input type="text" id="amount_milk" name="amount" ><br>
<input type = "checkbox" name="cb" checked="true">$20：<input type="text" id="amount_soymlik" name="amount"><br>
<input type = "checkbox" name="cb" checked="true">$30：<input type="text" id="amount_blacktea" name="amount" ><br>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="Totalamount()">Count</button>
<p>Total = <span id="result">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code:

- Fist use inputs of type number `<input type="number" name="amount">` to accept only numbers from your end users
- Then, you can work with indexed arrays like `[...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cb"]')]` and loop only one time with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the `total`

Code example:

```js
function Totalamount() {
  const inputNumberArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cb"]')]
  const inputAmountArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="amount"]')]
  const priceArr = [10, 20, 30]
  const total = inputNumberArr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    const num = c.checked ? +inputAmountArr[i].value : 0
    return a + num * priceArr[i]
  }, 0)
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '$' + 0
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '$' + total
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked> $10：
  <input type="number" name="amount"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked> $20：
  <input type="number" name="amount"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked> $30：
  <input type="number" name="amount"><br>
</fieldset>

<button onclick="Totalamount()">Count</button>
<p>Total = <span id="result">
```